# Using OpenCV's Image Hashing Module from Python

Tags: python, opencv, phash

I want to use OpenCV's [perceptual hashing functions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d93/group__img__hash.html) from Python.

This isn't working.

```
import cv2
a_1 = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
cv2.img_hash_BlockMeanHash.compute(a_1)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'compute' requires a 'cv2.img_hash_ImgHashBase' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

And this is failing too

```
a_1_base = cv2.img_hash_ImgHashBase(a_1) 
cv2.img_hash_BlockMeanHash.compute(a_1_base)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'img_hash_ImgHashBase' or its derivative)
```

Colab notebook showing this:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x5ZxMBD3wFts2WKS4ip3rp4afDx0lGhi

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/27/image-hashing-opencv-python/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a common compatibility gap that the OpenCV python interface has with the C++ interface (i.e. the classes don't inherit from each other the same way). There are the [`*_create()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/df/d55/classcv_1_1img__hash_1_1BlockMeanHash.html#ac18b32b0585dd07302a5667458797338) static functions for that.

So you should use:

```py
hsh = cv2.img_hash.BlockMeanHash_create()
hsh.compute(a_1)
```

In a copy of your collab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CLJNPPbeO3CiQ2d8JgPxEINpr2oNMWPh#scrollTo=OdTtUegmPnf2

Comment: it returns an array, how to get one number?

Comment: hash_xor = reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y, hash[0]) ?

Comment: It gives me following error: `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'img_hash'`. My `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` version is 4.3.0

Comment: Removing `opencv-python` and reinstalling it, solved the isuue!

Answer (score 10):

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python    #img_hash in this one
```

(https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Answer (score 6):

Here I show you how to compute 64-bit pHash with OpenCV.
I defined a function which returns unsigned, 64-bit integer pHash from a color BGR cv2 image passed-in:

```
import cv2
    
def pHash(cv_image):
        imgg = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        h=cv2.img_hash.pHash(imgg) # 8-byte hash
        pH=int.from_bytes(h.tobytes(), byteorder='big', signed=False)
        return pH
```

You need to have installed and import cv2 for this to work.

Comment: Is there a way to generate larger than 8-byte hash? for example 16-byte.